# How to TDD (Test-Driven-Development) a model that is related to data persistence?

Tags: tdd, xctest

Assume that I have a boolean that indicates whether the app is launched for the very first time or not (so I can show some guides for the first time)

I encapsulated that boolean into a model class (may be called `AppContext`)

```
class AppContext {
    var isFirstLaunch: Bool
    var otherAppScopeVar: Int
    // ...
}
```

Can I test this kind of things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't!

you should only test your application behavior in those two scenarios.

you need to execute your application after injecting that data with its two different states in order to test both scenarios.

Comment: Thanks, (for future readers) I should use 'dependency injection' technic to inject a mocked context to the other part of my app and test both two states.